# Inserir Múltiplos Dados de um Form Dinâmico no MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, script

Não tenho muito conhecimento em PHP e estou com um formulário onde o usuário tem alguns campos para preencher e gravar no banco de dados SQL, sendo que um campo deste form será dinâmico onde o usuário poderá adicionar quantos campos forem necessários a partir de um botão "+".

Até aqui está funcionando. Estou inserindo os dados de acordo com o desejado... Mas eu quero que este dado que está sendo inserido, seja adicionado para um cliente específico....

O sistema está assim:
1 - Página de cadastro de cliente
2 - Inserir um serviço destinado para este cliente cadastrado... Vou inserir este serviço após o cliente ser cadastrado posteriormente....

Eu quero é exatamente o que está acontecendo com este forum... Esta pergunta está relacionado ao meu login e ID (Provavelmente)...

Fiz um minis sistema teste para resolver apenas este prolema com poucos campos:
index.php

- jsFiddle demo




  Adicionar


 




  



    $(window).load(function(){
$(function(){
    
    //Cria uma função para Criar os campos Nome e Telefone
    function createDivFields(num){
        /*
         Criamos a variavel, e atribuimos os campos que serão criados;
         Utilizamos o colchetes nos nomes do campos para informar que os dados 
         em forma de array;
         Adiciona uma div, para que nela seja criado novos campos extras;
         E um link para para chamar o evento de adicionar;
        */
        var html  = '';
            html += 'Curso : ';
            html += 'Institui\u00e7\u00e3o: ';
            html += 'Carga Hor\u00e1ria : ';
            /*html += 'Add Telefone';*/
            html += '';
            html += '';
            return html;
    }
    
    //Cria a função para adicionar os campos extras de telefone
    function createFieldTel(num){
        /*
         Repare que é informado que terá um parametro;
         Será por ele iremos identificar de quem pertence esses campos;
        */
        var tel  = ' Telefone :';
            tel += '';
            tel += '
';
            return tel;
    }
    
    //cria uma função para conta os campos criados
    function getTotalItems(){
        //Contamos o total de campos, e diminuimos 1
        //Porque o array é iniciado seu indice com 0
        return $(".items").length;
    }
    
    //Adiciona os nome e telefone
    $("#add").click(function(){
        //Adicionado no final do elemento ( #boxFields) os campos
        var totalField = getTotalItems();
        $("#boxFields").append(createDivFields(totalField));
        return false;
    });
    
    //Adiciona os campos extras
    $(".addTel").live('click', function(){
        /*
            Utilizamos Live para atribui o evento click ao link addTel
            Isso porque como criamos dinamicamente esse elemento
            ele ainda não está no DOM, quando o jQuery vai executar
        */
        
        //recupera a posição
        var position = $(this).attr('data-id');
        
        //Voltamos um elemento (parent);
        //e depois buscamos .item, informando que precisa ser o primeiro encontrado
        //Adiciona no final do elemento (.item) os novos campos
        
        $(this).parent().children('.item:first').append(createFieldTel(position));
        
        return false;
    });

});
});//]]>

---

form2.php

include 'conexao.php';
$curso = $_POST['curso'];
$local = $_POST['local'];
$ch = $_POST['ch'];

$tamanho = count($curso)-1;
for ($f = 0; $f <= $tamanho; $f++)
{

$sql = "INSERT INTO testar (curso,local,ch) VALUES ('".$curso[$f]."', '".$local[$f]."', '".$ch[$f]."')" or die ("
Problemas ao selecionar a base de dados do sistemas: " . mysqli_error() . "");
$usuario_conect = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

echo "$curso[$f] - $local[$f] - $ch[$f]

";}
$cadastrados = mysqli_affected_rows();

echo 'Usuários cadastrados: ' . $cadastrados;

mysqli_close ($usuario_conect);

---

Banco de dados
Banco teste

Tabela cliente
id, nome, servico

tabela servicos
id_servico, servico, ch

Então, Preciso conectar os serviços que são inseridos ao cliente referente a cada serviço...
Sabendo que todas essas informações sõ inseridas dinamicamente via form...
NÃO EXISTE UMA QUANTIDADE DE SERVIÇOS PRE-DEFINIDOS, eles querem ter a liberdade de inserir quantos serviços forem necessários e ligar a cada cliente ao serviço solicitado...
Espero que me ajudem... kkkkk

Answer (score -1):

A sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, posso não ter percebido bem o que pretende, iria sugerir criar os novos campos com Ajax, e fazer um POST com um array, este array irá conter todos os valores nestes novos campos.

Outra possível solução seria ter campos de inserção de texto para adicionar, com o seu respetivo botão, e uma tabela com os valores adicionados, nesta tabela pode-se adicionar também um botão para remover.

[image: Exemplo da segunda parte]

Na imagem, o "+" segue para um post que adiciona e de seguida atualiza a lista usando Ajax.

Comment: Fala meu camarada... É mais ou menos isso... Eu faço o POST em JAVASCRIPT com todo os valores em um ARRAY... O problema é o seguinte: Quando eu visualizar o cliente eu quero que venha todos os serviços adicionados a esse cliente.... Como eu vou fazer isso no banco? vou inserir uma tabela nova pra cada serviço? Como eu vou buscar esses dados no banco MYSQL ? Essas são minhas dúvidas... Entendeu ?

Comment: Nesses casos eu uso uma tabela de ligação, 
Neste caso teria os IDs dos Clientes e os IDs dos serviços, ambos os campos são chaves primárias.


Ex (Isto é SQL server mas deve ser semelhante em Mysql): 

`Select * from Clientes C
left join Clientes_Servicos CS on C.ID=CS.ID_Cliente
left join Servicos S on CS.ID_Servico=S.ID`

Comment: Obrigado irmão pela ajuda..... Na verdade vou fazer isso mesmo... Uma tabela que liga os serviços aos clientes... abraços